# how to remove input buffer from java

Tags: java, arrays, string, buffer

I'm trying to input a certain number of strings but the last input gets a new line as input automatically. I need to remove the input buffer plz help

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = input.nextInt();     //n is my input number
String[] arr = new String[n];
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    arr[i] = input.nextLine();
}
```

If I enter n=5 as input and when i print the array my last input string goes missing and is replaced by a new line character

Comment: Just to ask something, Is there any other way to input a string as I'm interested in only entering strings without spaces. I don't want to use nextLine() function if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just consume the new line character after the first int:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = input.nextInt();     //n is my input number
input.nextLine();

String[] arr = new String[n];
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    arr[i] = input.nextLine();
}
```

Demo to make sure we agree on what the code should be doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text =
            "5\n" +
            "line 1\n" +
            "line 2\n" +
            "line 3\n" +
            "line 4\n" +
            "line 5\n" +
            "line 6\n";

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes()));

    int n = input.nextInt();     //n is my input number
    input.nextLine();

    String[] arr = new String[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr)); // [line 1, line 2, line 3, line 4, line 5]
}
```

Comment: I'd be surprised by that. You're iterating from 0 to n-1, that should yield exactly n lines

Comment: Sorry i mean to say that when i print the array my last input string goes missing and its replaced by new line character

Comment: I'll show you a demo of the code above and you'll tell me what was your expected output vs what is the actual output

Comment: ya it worked i got to know the error. Sorry i misunderstood the concept

Comment: Alright, no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

The call to `nextInt()` won't consume the new line you enter in the console, so you can consume the extra newline by using `Scanner.nextLine()` instead of `nextInt()` and converting it to an `int`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       //Convert the int to a String
       int n = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());//n is my input number
       String[] arr = new String[n];
       int i, j;
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           arr[i] = input.nextLine();
       }
       for (String s : arr) {
           System.out.println(s);
       }
 }
```

Comment: This solved my problem, Im new to java so could you explain in more detail this line `int n = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());`

Comment: As others said in their answer, `nextInt()` doesn't consume the first newline character, which is why your first line was empty. Check out the demo snippet in my answer and try removing the first `nextLine` and see what happens.

Comment: `input.nextLine()` is returning a `String` which you need to convert to an `int` to use in the for loop. The conversion of an `String` to an `int` is done through `Integer.parseInt(String)`. When you enter the number in the console and hit enter, the extra newline is not consumed by the `nextInt()` by default so I used the `nextLine()` which will by default skip one new line after the number.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextInt()` only consumes the integer that is given during input. So, if you provide an integer as input say `5` and press enter, then `Scanner.nextInt()` will only consume `5` and the enter/return is passed onto `nextLine`. This is why you think, that you are able to input 1 less.

So, after `Scanner.nextInt()`, you should add a `Scanner.nextLine()` just to consume the enter/return key

Comment: or you could use input.nextInt() and then use input.next() wherever required